# Change the appearance of Textbox to show number of characters required

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

So, I have a textbox in a WPF application. User enters characters into the textbox. I want to change the display of the textbox so that it shows number of characters required.[image: The number of characters may be dynamic]

Comment: How do you want to show the number of characters, inside the textbox buy grayed, outside the textbox maybe..?

Comment: Actually no. of characters will not be shown but only "space" required for the required characters will be displayed i.e; the above shown textbox requires 14 characters as the spaces are separated by a separator.